# Inheritance and subflows with Spring WebFlow in grails

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spring-webflow

Spring WebFlow supports some advanced reuse features like flow inheritance and subflows. Using this features in SWF xml definitions is pretty easy, for example:

```
<flow parent="parent">
<subflow-state id="addGuest" subflow="createGuest">
```

Can I use these features with weblflows in Grails?
Can I define these using the SWF groovy dsl?
How can I use Spring WebFlow definitions in grails?

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the Grails documentation: http://grails.org/doc/1.1.1/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.5%20Web%20Flow

Grails supports subflows via the DSL, I haven't tried inheritance.

cheers

Lee

Comment: Did already, just don't see how to specify that one flow is inheriting another? Or at least how to use xml definition of a flow? Documentation does not mention any of this.

Comment: I've never tried either of those so can't help you there sorry! Grails is just adding a layer on top of WebFlow so you should be able to use the normal 'Spring way' to do things. You might be able to work out what it's doing from the Grails source code for the WebFlowBuilder and which classes use it.